# Bash outputting kill usage

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, scripting

I have a bash script as follows:

```
if [[ "$1" == "stop"  ]]; then

 echo "[$(date +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S:%s')]: Killing all active watchers" >> $LOG

 kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep "processname1" | grep -v "grep" | grep -v "$$" | awk 
 '{print $2}' | xargs)

 echo "[$(date +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S:%s')]: Killing all current processname2 
 processes" >> $LOG

 kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep "processname2" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}' | 
 xargs)

 exit 0
```

when i run 'x service stop', the following is outputted:

```
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill 
-l [sigspec]
Killed
```

How do i stop the kill usage being displayed? It is successfully killing the process, however the fact that the usage is displayed is causing AWS CodeDeploy to fail.

Thanks!

Comment: Run `bash -x yourscript` to log the `kill` command it actually invokes, and the issue should become obvious. That said, `pkill` is a much more appropriate tool for the job (and better than *that* is using a built-to-purpose process supervision system -- systemd, upstart, launchd, runit, etc -- which doesn't need to grep the process table because supervised processes are running as its direct children; such a system also gets immediately notified when one of its children dies instead of needing to poll if you want to configure automated-restart support).

Comment: ...also, why the `| xargs`? `grep | grep -v | awk` is just silly, too -- `awk` can do all the work itself: `ps -ef | awk '/processname1/ && ! /awk/ { print $2 }'`

Comment: I suspect you have no such processes running, so the ps pipeline returns an empty string. `kill -9` with no pids will give you have usage message.

Comment: @glennjackman, I agree, but I'm hoping to lead the OP to discover that themselves via enabling logging. :)

Comment: @AdamHall ...btw, consider `exec {log_fd}>>"$LOG"` just *once* at the top of the script, and then you can use `>&$log_fd` on any command you want to log stdout of without re-opening the file separately for each `echo`. (If supporting bash before 4.1 you'll need to hardcode a file descriptor number rather than letting the shell assign one and set a variable as above).

Comment: (As a different aside, treating any content on stderr as meaning that a process failed does not speak well of AWS CodeDeploy honoring UNIX conventions -- stderr is supposed to be available for all diagnostic content -- status logging, progress bars, etc -- not just errors. Unless you're running `set -e` earlier in your script so it isn't getting to the `exit 0` after a nonzero exit from any unchecked command; in that case, it's your fault).

Answer (score 1):

Adam, please note that this is really just a comment with formatting. Don't take this as a real answer to your question. Please focus on the constructive comments to your question.

In my mis-spent youth, I wrote this bash function to do the `ps -ef | grep ....` madness:

```
# ps-grep
psg() { 
    local -a patterns=()
    (( $# == 0 )) && set -- $USER
    for arg do
        patterns+=("-e" "[${arg:0:1}]${arg:1}")
    done
    ps -ef | grep "${patterns[@]}"
}
```

using the knowledge that the *pattern* `[p]rocessname` will not match the *string* `[p]rocessname`

Comment: ...though `pgrep` will do this, and also be smart enough to not match either itself or its parent process.

Comment: Yes, I know. I think I came up with this when I was working on a Solaris 8 box, so I didn't have GNU tools.